# AR Quick Look - Using double sided Materials in USDZ is not displayed

Tags: swift, usdz, arquicklook

Using a double sided Material in USDZ Files is not displayed when opening the model in AR Quick Look. Only one side is displayed. Even when the model is displayed correctly when opening in Xcode or other tools. Seems like AR Quick Look is ignoring that setting. Are there any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved with the latest iOS / iPadOS 15 beta release